How to create a dynamic DTO in .Net Core Web api
I need to create an API for managing permissions settings for a user role.
For that when I create a role in the system, same API call should contain a list of permissions associated for that Role.
My Controller's post end point will be as follows.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveData([FromBody]RoleDto role)
{
    //Code to save Role
    return Ok(role);
}

Here my RoleDto will be as follows
public class RoleDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Permissions Permissions { get; set; }
}

Also my Permissions Dto will be as follows.
public class Permissions
{
    public bool AddUser { get; set; }
    public bool EditUser { get; set; }
    public bool DeleteUser { get; set; }
    public bool ReadUser { get; set; }
    public bool ManageLocations { get; set; }
    public bool ManageAssignment { get; set; }
}

Here my concern is if when my code grows and the number of permissions increase, how can I manage the Permissions Dto without code change? To make my point clear, Now there are 6 permissions AddUser,EditUser,DeleteUser,ReadUser,ManageLocations and ManageAssignment. After few years defenitely new permissions will come. How can I make the permissions Dto unchanged?  Is it possible to make this permissions Dto dynamic?
I have saved all available permissions in a master collection like follows.
{
        "PartitionKey": "Permission",
        "PermissionList": [
            "AddUser",
            "EditUser",
            "DeleteUser",
            "ReadUser",
            "ManageLocation",
            "ManageAssignment"
        ],
        "Type": "PermissionList",
    }

Is it possible to change the Permissions Dto dynamically as new entries are added to Permission List collection?
Edit
The alternative which I figured out is as follows.
public class Permissions
{
    public List<string> PermissionsList { get; set; }
}

Here the problem is API's client application will not know which all permissions are available. In that case I need to expose another API which shows a list of Available permissions. Is there any better options for this?

Why not return a Dictionary<string, bool>? That way you don't need another endpoint to get available permissions.

Still we cannot fill the dictionary along the DTO right? Once the client send the payload to API, they can fill the details in dictionary. But still the question remains as how will the user know the list of permissions.  public class Permissions
{
public Dictionary<string, bool> PermissionsList { get; set; }
} This is what you meant right? @sr28

In that case this would sound like something you would put in the API documentation. If the permissions are likely to change over time it sounds easier to maintain documentation rather than having to do a code change as well just for the user to know what they can pass.

It is not possible to create a dynamic class or record structure. The reason why permissions are generally kept hard-coded is to allow for comparisons without losing performance during the authorization phase. If you do not mind connecting to a data store on every request that comes to your API and checking authorization, and the performance loss that this will cause, you can set up your authorization structure to scale horizontally by querying the roles and permission relationships on every request in custom Authorize attribute.
